# How to display and bind in WPF variable number (and type) of data attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an object type (call it "vehicle") that can have a variable number of attributes, each of a different type (some attributes are a single number, some are three numbers in one attribute).  The order of the attributes matters (they are geometric transformations).

I have captured the attributes of the vehicle class in a `List` collection. A quick summary of the classes (Assume these are all properties with underlying fields):

*** See Edit Below ***

```
class Transformation 
{
    string Type;   // Might make sense to make this an enum
    float[] Value; // This always holds either 1, 3, or 5 values depending on Type.
}

class Vehicle 
{
    List<Transformation> MyTransformations;
}
```

When I select a particular `vehicle` instance, I would like to display the transformations in a data panel and bind to them so the user can edit them (and add/delete transformations).

What is the best strategy for implementing this in WPF? Do I build a scrollable `StackPanel` via code?  Is there a "smart" way to do it via type templates?  Is it a mistake to hold the different length transformations in one class (do I need to break up into a different class for each transformation type)?

I'm envisioning the data panel look something like this:

```
Transformations 
Rotate       6.7  2.3  8.7 
UniformScale 1.0 
Translate    2.2  2.0  1.0
```

With a scroll bar running on the right side since I don't know how many transformations each object might have.

*** Edit ***
Per a suggestion in a comment and further experimentation, I have made 3 separate classes for the 3 kinds of attributes.  They are all derived from `Transformation` so that I still have a `List<Transformation>` in my `Vehicle` class.

So my question now is how to build a scrollable display that holds a variable number of the `Transformation` objects?

Comment: I don't see anything here that needs to be done in a code-behind. You can do this using quite a few different types of controls like a list view and a data template. It all depends on how you want it to look/behave.

Comment: I've added some sample output on how I want it to look. In terms of behavior, once an attribute is changed in the GUI it should be updated in the data.  This is all local, not tied to a database

Comment: You probably do need to adjust your class - it would be easier to do three classes, for your one / three / five float values, and then use data templates to select among them.  The big problem is that if you bind an array of primatives to an items control, you can generate a control that binds to each item, but only one-way.  Two-way binding requires you to bind to a property of the objects in your collection.  If you can separate out datatemplates by 1, 3, or 5 floats, though, you can databind Value[0], etc.

Comment: PMV, I agree; I pretty much came to the same conclusion. Arrays and bindings are ugly  I have done that and modified the question accordingly to focus on building the WPF GUI to account for the variable number of `Transformation` to display

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with one potential solution based on @PMV's comment.  As mentioned in the Edit to my original question I have a `List<Transformation>` to hold my list of transformations, and three different transformation classes derived from the base `Transformation`.  Each of the three classes has a different type of `Value`. (Could be a `float` or one of two special classes I created that can store 3 or 5 floats -- not in an array).

I then created 3 user controls, one for each of the three derived classes.  The user controls are a basic 'grid' with a text box for each `float`.  An example for the 3 float data type shown below:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="Type" 
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="{Binding .Type, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
        />
        <TextBox x:Name="X" 
            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="{Binding .TransValue.X, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
        />
        <TextBox x:Name="Y" 
            Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="{Binding .TransValue.Y, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
        />
        <TextBox x:Name="Z" 
            Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="{Binding .TransValue.Z, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" 
        />

</Grid>
```

In my main page I then created a `ListView` with data templates for each of the 3 transformation classes I have.  Two way binding works as expected, and the display looks perfect, with any combination of `Transformation` derived objects being shown.  Code to create the `ListView`:

```
   <ListView x:Name="listView">  
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>    
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:Trans1}">
                <UserControls:UserControlTrans1/>
            </DataTemplate>                   
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:Trans3}">
                <UserControls:UserControlTrans3/>
            </DataTemplate>    
        </ListView.Resources>    
    </ListView>
```

One important detail is the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property.  This stretches out the user controls to the full width of the list, which makes the list look nice and uniform, as opposed to every entry being a different width item.